# Как изменить порядок букв в словах?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дано 2 слова через пробел:

```
буханка хлеба
```

На выходе мы должны получить:

```
хуханка блеба
```

т.е как поменять местами первые буквы?

Comment: ну и в чем возникла проблема? split по пробелам, переставьте первые буквы и join

Comment: Я не пойму как переставить, пример кода можно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Через регулярные выражения, используя захват групп:

```
import re
text = 'буханка хлеба'
new_text = re.sub('(.)(.+?) (.)(.+?)', r'\3\2 \1\4', text)
print(new_text)  # хуханка блеба
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a1, a2 = 'буханка хлеба'.split()
print(f'{a2[0]}{a1[1:]} {a1[0]}{a2[1:]}')
```